# Difference between distributed and non-distributed arrays in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

Suppose that we have this code in MATLAB:

```
parpool('local',2) % Create a parallel pool
W = ones(6,6);
W = distributed(W); % Distribute to the workers
spmd
    T = W*2; % Calculation performed on workers, in parallel
    % T and W are both codistributed arrays here
end
T % View results in client.
whos % T and W are both distributed arrays here
delete(gcp) % Stop pool
```

1. I read in documentation that the difference between normal arrays and distributes array is : When we use distributed arrays, these arrays directly send to workers and there isn't any array on clients. So we don't have any access to these arrays in client? Is this only discrepancy?
2. What is the difference in structure and output of code if we remove `W = distributed(W);` line? What is purpose of using distributed array?
3. What is difference between `distributed` and `codistributed`. As i read in documentation we can only use `codistributed` in `spmd` block. Is that ture?

Comment: This question seems a bit too broad to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Distributed arrays are stored on the workers, not the client, and operations on them are carried out in parallel by the workers - that's the point of them.

The difference between distributed and codistributed arrays is only one of perspective. From the point of view of the client, they are distributed arrays; from the point of view of the workers, they are codistributed arrays.

To illustrate, first start a pool:

```
>> parpool('local',2)
```

create an array:

```
>> W = ones(6,6);
```

`W` is stored on the client.

Now create a distributed array from `W`:

```
>> V = distributed(W);
```

`V` is stored on the workers, split across each worker. You still have access to `V` from the client, but when you do so it is pulling `V` back from the workers.

```
>> V
V =
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Note that in the Workspace Browser, `V` is there as a 6x6 distributed array, not a 6x6 double like `W`.

Now although from the point of view of the client `V` is a distributed array, from the point of view of the workers, `V` is a codistributed array.

```
>> spmd; disp(V); end
Lab 1: 
          LocalPart: [6x3 double]
      Codistributor: [1x1 codistributor1d]

Lab 2: 
          LocalPart: [6x3 double]
      Codistributor: [1x1 codistributor1d]
```

You can see that `V` is codistributed, and that only half of it (6x3) is stored on each worker.

When you do something with `V`, that happens on the workers, in parallel, and the results are stored on the workers as a distributed/codistributed array:

```
>> spmd; T = V*2; end
>> spmd; disp(T); end
Lab 1: 
          LocalPart: [6x3 double]
      Codistributor: [1x1 codistributor1d]

Lab 2: 
          LocalPart: [6x3 double]
      Codistributor: [1x1 codistributor1d]
```

You have access to `T` from the client just as you did with `V`, but to explicitly bring it back, use `gather`:

```
>> S = gather(T);
```

Note that `S` is now a 6x6 double, not a distributed array.

Comment: Thank you for answer Sam. So what is purpose of defining `coddistributed`array in `spmd` block? How we can use this structure in your codes? Suppose that we have `ones(6,6,'coddistributed')` in `spmd` block.

Comment: Well, you might wish to create codistributed variables from within your `spmd` block. That syntax allows you to do that. For example, if you try `spmd; X = ones(6,6, 'codistributed'); end`, `X` will be a distributed (from the client) or codistributed (from the workers) array. That might be a useful thing to do - and of course you can do more complex things than `ones` as well.

Comment: So we have same functionality in both structures? Is this true?

Comment: They are not two different structures. Distributed arrays _are_ codistributed arrays. When you are on the client, you (and code) see them as distributed arrays. When you are on a worker, you (and code) see them as codistributed arrays. It's the same array, just described and seen in two different ways.

Comment: To emphasize, create `V` as in my answer. Then type `class(V)`. You'll see `distributed`. Now type `spmd; disp(class(V)); end`. You'll see that both workers see it as `codistributed`.

Answer (score 1):

To 1.) There are surely other minor discrepancies, but at least the way you index and manipulate its elements should be the same.

To 2.) You could easily try out for yourself. Anyway, the result is a [Composite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/composite.html), that is the normal array way copied to each worker in the execution of the `spmd` block and the calculation performed multiple times and each result stored. I would use "normal" type for constant input data (parameters) and `distributed` for variables which are used for computating the output (and defines their size).

Example:

```
x = distributed(1:100); % variable, output will be calculated on -> distributed
a = 5; % amplitude (constant parameter -> "normal")
spmd
  y = a * sin(x);
end
y
```

This also explains the purpose of `distributed`: enable parallel calculation on a matrix.

To 3.: `Distributed` means its elements are spread over workers. `Codistributed` means its elements are also spread but in the same way to something that is also `distributed` (which among others implies equal size). I guess (but are not sure) that the `codistributed` property stays as long as the parallel pool stays open, but from outside the spmd block they can only be accessed as `distributed` arrays.

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/codistributed.html) says:

> Codistributed arrays on workers that you create inside spmd statements
>   or from within task functions of communicating job can be accessed as
>   distributed arrays on the client.